# Laptop appears to boot to broken GRUB; fails all boot options

Tags: fedora

When I boot my computer, it goes straight to GRUB, but no commands return output. When I open the bootloader and try to boot, it won't boot from the HDD, a USB, or an SD card. It will only boot from a CD, but I don't know how to fix anything from there. Recently I installed OpenRazer and had to install I different kernel-devel version, which broke my wifi. After that it worked fine, until recently I tried turning it on and ran into the above issue.
More Information:
Laptop: Dell Latitude E5410
Distro: Fedora 35 Design suite
Unknown kernel and kernel-devel versions.

Comment: It's an old laptop that still has BIOS, right? You may need to reinstall Grub then.

Comment: Furthermore, typically laptops don't boot from the internal SD card reader (most will boot from a SD card with an USB adapter); it should boot from a properly made bootable USB stick (again, the installer/live must support BIOS mode which isn't a given nowadays).